# Take table element on double click tableviewer Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently using to get the selection on selection change on a tableviewer.

```
public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();
                Row rowData = (Row) selection.getFirstElement();
            item=rowData.item
}
```

I want to take the selected item on mouse double click:

```
public void mouseDoubleClick(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)table.getSelection()[0];   
                Row rowData = (Row) selection.getFirstElement();
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get null everytime. What can I do to take these informations on mouse double click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IDoubleClickListener` to handle double click events for a `TableViewer` (or a `TreeViewer`).

```
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();
    }
});
```